# JavaScript reduce throwing error for more than two items

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
const arr = [
  { someProp: [{ amount: 10 }]},
  { someProp: [{ amount: 12 }]},
];
```

and then this reduce fn:

```
const sum = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.someProp[0].amount + curr.someProp[0].amount);
```

It works if there are two items in the array but with three it throws:

*Cannot read property '0' of undefined"*

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why I (and [some](https://twitter.com/bterlson/status/1099010861065068544) [others](https://twitter.com/jaffathecake/status/1213077702300852224)) just don't see value in using `reduce`; use a loop instead. Clean, simple, clear. (Other than in a functional programming project with prebuilt, tested reducer functions.) It's just far too complicated relative to its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need only to return the accumulator + the new value.

You want to begin with `0` i guess so you need to add `0` as second parameter

```js
const arr =
    [
      { someProp: [{ amount: 10 }]},
      { someProp: [{ amount: 12 }]},
      { someProp: [{ amount: 12 }]},
    ];
    
const sum = arr.reduce((acc, item) => item.someProp[0].amount + acc, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

If you want it more spicy here with destructuring

```js
const arr =
    [
      { someProp: [{ amount: 10 }]},
      { someProp: [{ amount: 12 }]},
      { someProp: [{ amount: 12 }]},
    ];
    
const sum = arr.reduce((acc, { someProp: [{ amount }] }) => amount + acc, 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a number. The value of `prev` is always the prior *return value* from the callback, not the previous element. Thus on the third iteration you're trying to use that number as if it were an object reference.

Add a second parameter (0) to the `.reduce()` call, and change the function to treat `prev` as the running total (a simple number):

```
const sum = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.someProp[0].amount, 0);
```

It works as-is when there are two elements because without that second parameter, the first iteration will see element 0 as `prev` and element 1 as `curr`.  That behavior works fine when you've got an array of numbers and you just want to perform a computation between them, but in this case you need that initial value explicitly there as the second argument.

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to get it to work: https://jsfiddle.net/bazxw7pm/ if you open the console you'll see the error

Answer (score 2):

Following @Pointy answer, this is how you can get it working with any number of elements:

```
const sum = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => prev + curr.someProp[0].amount, 0);
```

`prev` is always the previously returned element, so you can safely use it as a number (and since you're just summing it, you can use `0` as default, so the first time `reduce` is invoked the value of `prev` will be 0)

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative solution... Using `Array.filter()`.

```js
const arr = [{
    someProp: [{
      amount: 10
    }]
  },
  {
    someProp: [{
      amount: 12
    }]
  },
  {
    someProp: [{
      amount: -231
    }]
  },
  {
    someProp: [{
      amount: 21265
    }]
  },
  {
    someProp: [{
      amount: 1239
    }]
  },
  {
    someProp: [{
      amount: -6
    }]
  },
];
const sum = arr.filter((val, index) => {
  if (index > 0) {
    arr[index].someProp[0].amount = parseInt(val.someProp[0].amount) + parseInt(arr[index - 1].someProp[0].amount);
  }
  return index == arr.length - 1;
})[0].someProp[0].amount;

console.log(sum);
```